# java spring and bean garbage colletion

Tags: java, spring, garbage-collection

When a spring bean is eligible for garbage collection. POJO in java are not reachable by the mark-and-sweep algorithm will be claimed by the garbage collection. How this concept works in springs? As spring beans are invoked in spring context. The existence of spring bean is governed by the spring context. What determines when a bean memory can be reclaimed ? Does scope of the bean influence this, if so how ?

Please correct me if I wrong, or the question needs update for better penetration.

Answer (score 1):

If the Spring application context holds onto that reference, and the factory is still in scope, then the POJO is not eligible.

Scope does influence it.  Prototype and per-HTTP request scopes are cleaned up when the request scope ends.  Singletons remain in memory as long as the application context does.